# MFP 7.1 - Iphone All notifications disappearing after opening one of them

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a hybrid Mobile App and We have encountered this issue with push notification.

When one notification is clicked in IPhone all other notification disappears from the notification tray. Initial I though its the normal functioning of IOS. But if I compare with some other apps like Twitter or CNN , this issue does not happen. It allow you to click them one at a time. How can I add this feature to my mobile app.

Comment: Are you setting `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber` to `0`?

Comment: Actually as this is Hybrid app, I am not aware of this line of code you mentioned. But I know I can send these setting when Sending push, but at this point I am not sending any badge info.

Comment: incorrect badge, is that the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on one remote notification clearing the rest in notification center, is expected behaviour in MobileFirst hybrid application on iOS.

To the best of my understanding, iOS does not give a handle to individual remote notifications - so that you can single out one and clear only that.

Setting `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0` clears all remote notifications for the application, from notification center.

To workaround this, you can use local notifications which gives you a handle to individual local notification and you can use [cancelLocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelLocalNotification:) to remove the single notification.So, in the callback for a remote notification, a local notification is created with the payload ( from remote notification). This allows for clearing individual notifications.

To have this feature in MFP, you can submit a [Request for Enhancement](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).